# MYSQL Ranking Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck on how to modify my query to get the ranking results that I am looking for.  I have been looking at the questions and queries on SO but can not get the results. I can get the query to do the calculation and return data but the "rank" is not correct.  Any nudge would be fantastic!

Table 1 contains school data:

```
+-----+------------+---------------+
| SID | schoolName | schoolCountry |
+-----+------------+---------------+
|   1 | ASD        | UAE           |
|   2 | ASIJ       | Japan         |
|   3 | ASP        | France        |
+-----+------------+---------------+
```

Table 2 contains review data (my query has more columns, but this is how it works).

```
+-----+----------+--------+----+----+----+----+----+
| RID | schoolID | active | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 |
+-----+----------+--------+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1 |        1 |      1 |  8 |  9 |  5 |  1 |  9 |
|   2 |        2 |      1 |  7 |  6 |  6 |  7 |  9 |
|   3 |        1 |      0 |  1 |  4 |  7 |  8 |  5 |
|   4 |        3 |      1 |  2 | 10 |  6 |  7 |  5 |
+-----+----------+--------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I am trying to create different ranks (Country, Region, Overall) by averaging the overall review score for a school.  I am currently working on the country ranking and my query so far is.

```
SELECT SID, schoolName, rank, average 
FROM (
SELECT (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank,schools.SID, schools.schoolName,
ROUND(AVG(IF(reviews.active = 1, ((Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q12+Q13+Q14+Q15+Q16+Q17+Q18+Q19+Q20+Q21+Q22+Q23+Q24+Q25+Q26+Q27+Q28+Q29+Q30+Q31+Q32+Q33+Q34+Q35+Q36+Q37+Q38+Q39+Q40+Q41+Q42+Q43+Q44+Q45+Q46+Q47+Q48+Q49+Q50+Q51+Q52)/(52*10)*10), NULL)) ,1) AS average
FROM schools
RIGHT JOIN reviews ON reviews.schoolID = schools.SID
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS vars
WHERE schools.schoolCountry = 'United Arab Emirates'
GROUP BY schools.SID

) as order_ranked  
ORDER BY `order_ranked`.`average`  DESC
```

My output comes back as:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------+------+---------+--+
| SID |               schoolName               | rank | average |  |
+-----+----------------------------------------+------+---------+--+
| 568 | GEMS Wellington Primary School         |    3 | 8.3     |  |
|   1 | American School of Dubai               |    1 | 8.1     |  |
| 561 | Dubai American Academy                 |    4 | 7.9     |  |
| 560 | Deira International School             |   11 | 7.7     |  |
| 569 | GEMS World Academy Dubai               |   10 | 7.0     |  |
| 570 | Greenfield Community School            |    8 | 6.7     |  |
| 565 | GEMS American Academy Abu Dhabi        |    6 | 6.0     |  |
| 584 | Universal American School              |    5 | 5.9     |  |
| 558 | American Academy In Al Mizhar          |    7 | 5.5     |  |
| 579 | The Cambridge High School Abu Dhabi    |    9 | 4.8     |  |
| 576 | Ras Al Khaimah English Speaking School |    2 | 4.3     |  |
+-----+----------------------------------------+------+---------+--+
```

As you can see it ranks, but not correctly.  I just can't figure out why.

Comment: `rank` should depend on the ordering of average..but there is no `order by` in the inner query.

Comment: Hi Vamsi, I tried to add ORDER BY average to the inner query by it still returns out of rank order and looks just like the above returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would be using `right join` for this.  In MySQL, you often have to sort in the subquery before using the variables.

```
SELECT SID, schoolName, (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank, average 
FROM (SELECT s.SID, s.schoolName,
ROUND(AVG(Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q12+Q13+Q14+Q15+Q16+Q17+Q18+Q19+Q20+Q21+Q22+Q23+Q24+Q25+Q26+Q27+Q28+Q29+Q30+Q31+Q32+Q33+Q34+Q35+Q36+Q37+Q38+Q39+Q40+Q41+Q42+Q43+Q44+Q45+Q46+Q47+Q48+Q49+Q50+Q51+Q52)/(52*10)*10)) AS average
      FROM schools s JOIN
           reviews r
           ON r.schoolID = s.SID 
      WHERE s.schoolCountry = 'United Arab Emirates' AND r.isactive = 1
      GROUP BY schools.SID
      ORDER BY average DESC
     ) sr CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rank := 0) AS vars
ORDER BY average  DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Rank should depend on the ordering of average..but there is no order by in the inner query. First compute the average and calculate rank thereafter. Also, i moved the `where` condition to `join` because the way you have it is equivalent to an inner join.

```
SELECT SID, schoolName, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, average 
FROM (
SELECT schools.SID, schools.schoolName,
ROUND(AVG(IF(reviews.active = 1, ((Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q12+Q13+Q14+Q15+Q16+Q17+Q18+Q19+Q20+Q21+Q22+Q23+Q24+Q25+Q26+Q27+Q28+Q29+Q30+Q31+Q32+Q33+Q34+Q35+Q36+Q37+Q38+Q39+Q40+Q41+Q42+Q43+Q44+Q45+Q46+Q47+Q48+Q49+Q50+Q51+Q52)/(52*10)*10), NULL)) ,1) AS average
FROM schools
RIGHT JOIN reviews ON reviews.schoolID = schools.SID AND schools.schoolCountry = 'United Arab Emirates'
GROUP BY schools.SID,schools.schoolName
) as order_ranked 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS vars 
ORDER BY `average` DESC
```

Comment: That worked beautifully, except for one issue.  I am getting a NULL value for one of the rows.  There are two schools with the same score?  But in my actual data that doesn't happen.  It's at rank 5 above, there is another NULL row with value 7.0.   But if I put there "WHERE" by country back out and not with the RIGHT JOIN it goes away.